# Elsa Workflow - Email issues

Tags: c#, .net-core, workflow, elsa-workflows

I'm trying to get a basic Elsa workflow to run. I have the Elsa Server running with my workflow definition, it's very simple - a http Endpoint and then SendEmail. Screenshots below.

[Workflow Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo5cy.png)

[SendEmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWE9b.png)

I'm using postman to test it but every time I get the following error message on the new instance of the workflow in the SendEmail:

```
{
"Type": "System.ArgumentNullException",
"Message": "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'host')",
"StackTrace": "   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, Boolean doAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at        Elsa.Activities.Email.Services.MailKitSmtpService.SendOnlineMessage(MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Elsa.Activities.Email.Services.MailKitSmtpService.SendAsync       (ActivityExecutionContext context, MimeMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Elsa.Activities.Email.SendEmail.OnExecuteAsync(ActivityExecutionContext context)\r\n   at        Elsa.Services.Workflows.WorkflowRunner.TryExecuteActivityAsync(ActivityOperation activityOperation, ActivityExecutionContext activityExecutionContext, IActivity activity, CancellationToken        cancellationToken)",
"InnerException": null
}
```

My startup.cs has SMTP configured:

```
var elsaSection = Configuration.GetSection("Elsa");

// Elsa services.
services
    .AddElsa(elsa => elsa
    .UseEntityFrameworkPersistence(ef => ef.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;Database=Elsa;User ID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;"))
    .AddConsoleActivities()
    .AddHttpActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Server").Bind)
    .AddEmailActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Smtp").Bind)
    .AddQuartzTemporalActivities()
    .AddWorkflowsFrom<Startup>() 
  );

// Elsa API endpoints.
services.AddElsaApiEndpoints();

// For Dashboard.
services.AddRazorPages();
```

My appsettings.json is as follows:

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
   }
 },
 "Elsa": {
    "Server": {
      "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5001"
    }
  },
  "Smtp": {
    "Host": "smtpserver.domainname",
    "Port": "25",
    "DefaultSender": "xxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
   },
   "AllowedHosts": "*"
 }
```

The smtp host is specified as the network smtp server, so I don't understand why I'm getting a missing host parameter error.
If anyone out there can help, it would be much appreciated.

P.S. I have created my own custom function to send an email using the same smtp details and that works well, but I need to use the standard version.

Thanks!

Comment: Try setting SSL to false.  Also the From address and the email account have to be the same.

Comment: I just tried to reproduce the exact same scenario but it worked well for me. How about trying the following first: clone Elsa Core, checkout the master branch, start the Elsa.Samples.Server.Host project and import your workflow there. Make sure to have Smtp4Dev running. If this works (as it should), then start comparing with your project.  You could replace the package references with Elsa project references that you cloned and use the debugger to see why it thinks Host is null. If you can't figure it out, feel free to send me a (stripped down) version of your project (find me on Discord).

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you need to set your smtp configuration into Elsa tag like this:

```
 "Elsa": {
    "Server": {
      "BaseUrl": "http://localhost:5001"
    },
    "Smtp": {
    "Host": "smtpserver.domainname",
    "Port": "25",
    "DefaultSender": "xxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxx.com"
   }
  },
  ....
```

because when you user:

```
var elsaSection = Configuration.GetSection("Elsa");
```

and try to get the smtp config section:

```
.AddEmailActivities(elsaSection.GetSection("Smtp").Bind)
```

`elsaSection` expect the smtp to be inside the `Elsa` section.

or you can use:

```
smtpSection = Configuration.GetSection("Smtp");
.AddEmailActivities(smtpSection.Bind)
```